# implementing ValidationMessageFor

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-2

I was working on migrating MVC1 app to MVC2 today and i have come across a problem while changing the ValidationMessage to ValidationMessageFor implementation.

The below is the selectlist in my View

```
<%=Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SecurityQuestions[0].Question,  "Some Security question", new { @class = "form_element_select" })%>
```

The below code works fine and i can see the validation message came from modelstate.

```
<%= Html.ValidationMessage("SecurityQuestions_0__Question")%>
```

but this one does not work:

```
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SecurityQuestions[0].Question)%>
```

SecurityQuestions is a generic list in my model

```
public List<SecurityQuestion> SecurityQuestions { get; set; }
```

Is this somewhat a bug in "ValidationMessageFor" or am i missing something here?

I have previously asked [this question on asp.net forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1545006.aspx).

Comment: You say that it doesn't work, but what is actually the problem? Does it throw compilation errors? runtime? Does it not render? bind?

Comment: It does not validate. I dont see the error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is fixed in MVC V3

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that ValidationMessageFor only uses the last property name as validation message key.

In your case this means that:

```
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SecurityQuestions[0].Question) %>
```

equals

```
<%= Html.ValidationMessage("Question") %>
```

and not what you thought it would. Unfortunately in this case you will have to use the non-strong typed helper to have the whole string as it should be.

Comment: <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Question") %> will not work as the rendered client ID output of Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SecurityQuestions[0].Question... is SecurityQuestions_0__Question and realize that you are displaying multiple indexes of a generic list in the view.

Comment: @Murat: I know it doesn't work, that's why I suggested you use non-strong-typed helper for this particular case.

Comment: Since SecurityQuestions_0__Question is a rendered output for the dropdownlist, Html.ValidationMessageFor should also render the same client id. Do you think this is a bug or something?

Answer (score 0):

You can add error you want to see to ModelState, under key that is generated by **ValidationMessageFor**. 
Sure its a hack, but the fastest way to go. And it doesnt add any ugly **"SecurityQuestions_0__Question"** to your markup.