# Is it possible to have a strongly typed validation message in a ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

This works:  `@Html.ValidationMessage("Name")`

**Problem** Is it possible to get strongly typed helper working?:  `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EventInVM.Name)`

[image]

ViewModel:

```
public class EventViewModel
{
    public Event EventInVM { get; set; }
    public IList<Series> ListOfSeries { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(EventViewModel eventViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            SetupDropDownsStronglyTyped(eventViewModel);
            return View(eventViewModel);
        }

        uow.Add(eventViewModel.EventInVM);
        uow.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

View

```
   <h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Event</legend>
        @Html.Partial("_CreateOrEdit", Model)
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Partial

```
@model dave.Controllers.EventViewModel

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EventInVM.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EventInVM.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EventInVM.Name)
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using data annotations for your validation?  For example, does your `Event` type `Name` property have a `[Required]` attribute or anything like that?

Comment: No I'm not.  Am using LightSpeed as my ORM and a custom EntityModelBinder to flow through annotations.  I think this is working fine as the Validation Summary shows what I'd expect.. have uploaded a screenshot

Comment: OK.  I'm guessing the errors are getting added to the `ModelState.Errors` collection without the proper key.  If the error doesn't have a key that matches the property name, the `Html.ValdiationMessageFor` won't show it, but the summary still will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this answer here:
[implementing ValidationMessageFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681159/implementing-validationmessagefor)
I believe its because you are referencing another property off of a property.

Comment: Thanks @Adam.  Yes this pointed me to the weakly typed helpers which I've implemented above..  I wonder if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `@Html.Partial("_CreateOrEdit", Model)` use `@Html.EditorForModel()`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Event</legend>
        @Html.EditorForModel()
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

and then put the editor template inside `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/EventViewModel.cshtml`

Comment: Thanks @Darin - yeah I like using this better.  Didn't help with strongly typed helpers though.